# How do I get WebdriverIO autocomplete on VS Code

Tags: webdriver-io

Is there a way I can get autocomplete on VS Code for webdriverio?

Other code editors like Intellij provide something like Settings -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries
From there we can add a directory with webdriverio commands

How can I do similar thing with VS Code?

Answer (score 5):

my understanding is, vscode is built with `typescript` and by default it does not support autoComplete(Intellisense) on a package that is built with `javascript`. So all the js package creators would provide an `@types` file. These `@types` file help vscode to find all the function definitions, object properties. etc., etc., of your JS package and show as suggestions. Which in case here is `webdriverio` package.

So adding a `@types` dependency that is related to your JS package will mostly fix the issue.
i.e.,

```
npm install @types/webdriverio --save-dev
```

After adding the package, i started getting the browser object suggestions.

All the above works fine for [v4](http://v4.webdriver.io/) version of WDIO.

If you are using v5 version: Then as per their official [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/autocompletion.html) we need to create a `jsconfig.json` file on the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer worked well :

you need to install below dependency :

```html
if you are using webdriverio v4 (for cucumber BDD ) use below 
npm install @types/webdriverio@4 --save-dev

or use :
npm install @types/webdriverio --save-dev
```

[VSCode Intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/857lB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using ***@types/webdriverio*** is not suggested by webdriverio and it is now deprecated:
*npm WARN deprecated @types/webdriverio@5.0.0: This is a stub types definition. webdriverio provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.*

I would suggest to follow the official documentation by WebDriverIO [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/autocompletion.html):