# How to configure webdriver.io intellisense / autocomplete on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, webdriver-io

I am new to JS and trying to use VSCode for Webdriver.io programming.

As per webdriver.io website, instructions are available there for setting up it on IntelliJ:

But I was not able to find same for VSCode.

Kindly advise. Thanks

Comment: Please try the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502115/how-do-i-get-webdriverio-autocomplete-on-vs-code/48129883#48129883 Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Thanks for your timely help. Much appreciated.